# How to integrate road into landscape (low poly style)

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to integrate a road (that i did build using array and curve modifier) into a flat plane (low poly).

I can't figure out how to make the road 'cut' the plane; my end goal is to
achieve a look like the 2nd picture.

I've tried boolean but it gives weird results.

How would someone do it ?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You want the road to stay planar or should it follow the landscape?

Comment: It should follow the landscape but like 'cut' the landscape (as if i used the knife tool to create edges where the road goes).

Comment: Could you upload a sample blend file so that one can start from concrete elements? Please use this link to do it https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Added file in question.

Comment: To use the Boolean Modifier you would need the road to have enough volume to "consume" the landscape. Try convert it to a Mesh and extrude in the Z, then add a Boolean Modifier.

Comment: I did try that; then i end up with weird things; the extruded mesh doesn't cut the 'terrain' in a 'suqare' way (sorry hard to explain); and I do move it along Z axis so it's really cutting thru

Comment: You can knife project the road (eventually starting from a flat road) upon the landscape. That will draw/cut the landscape as the road is. But the result will be flat.

Comment: How to 'knife project' ? Is it a modifier ?

Comment: Not a modifier. First, to have all cuts, edit the road and delete all faces only. Go in top view ortho. Select the road, shift select the landscape. Enter edit mode and use knife project from the mesh menu.

Comment: ok it 'kinda' worked; i end up having some unclosed loops; i guess that's the best I can get ? 

I wonder how level designers draw huge maps; i bet there's a simpler solution.

Comment: You can also sculpt the road...

Comment: sculpt ? can you explain a bit more ? ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97931/discussion-between-disco-fever-and-lemon).